# Excel VBA check cell color with Activecell.Interior.color not working

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I wish to check whether a cell has a certain color. If true, I want this message box ("Cell Match Color"). Otherwise, I wish to have Message box ("Cell does not match color.")

```
Option Explicit
Sub Autoselect()
    Dim Refcolor As Long
    Set Refcolor = RGB(220, 230, 241)
    If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = Refcolor Then MsgBox ("Cell Match
    Color") Else: MsgBox ("Cell does not match color")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove keyword `Set` when you assign value to variable `Refcolor`.

`Set` is used to assign objects to variable and you are assigning primitive value.

```
Sub Autoselect()
    Dim Refcolor As Long

    Refcolor = RGB(220, 230, 241)

    If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = Refcolor Then
        MsgBox ("Cell Match Color")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Cell does not match color")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Solved the issue immediately. Thank you.